# Make Link Detected by NSDataDetector clickable in Swift 3 OS X

Tags: swift3

I thought that if the person posted a link within a description inside a textfield that I could make that link clickable.  So, I first thought I would need to detect the link (which I have done) then make it clickable...I have tried several different things but still nothing. I have the link printing to my console--I just need the link to be clickable within the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your label:

```
let label = UILabel()
let clickGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(click(_:)))
label.gestureRecognizers = [clickGesture]
 func click(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //do stuff on label click
}
```